# array (c style) cell content losing it's value when issue variable content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in the .h file:

```
double var1;
NSString *Items[90];
```

in the .m file:

```
var1 = 1000;
NSString  *j = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", var1 ];
Items[42] = [@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: j ];
```

see code above, the issue is that thru the app running i have a proc that needs this
Items[42] value however the value is not there anymore ( i didn't erase it ) but
the cell is completely empty no null or spaces, as if the cell value was released.

on the other hand if i just place in Items[42] some string with no attached variable (like var1)  (i.e. Items[42] = @"hello there"; )
then all is ok and the value of Items[42] is being preserved.

any idea why the cell when presented with a variable content (like var1 ) the cell lose content?

TIA

Comment: Do you use ARC? If you don't, then it _does_ get released (by the `NSAutoreleasePool`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference counter of temporary string is zero. It would be destroyed at any time. There are three options to solve the problem:

1. `Items[42] = [[@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: var1 ] retain];`
   In non-ARC env, and remember to call `[Items[42] release]` later.
2. Declare Items as `NSMutableArray*` or `NSArray*`, i.e. `NSMutableArray*`
   Items. Which will automatically manage the reference count of its
   objects
3. Convert the program to use ARC

For global (static) constant strings, they have an infinite reference counter, and would never be destroyed.

Comment: I changed to: `code` NSString *jj = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10] retain];
    
    Item1040[42] = [[@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: jj ] retain];      but still same results it lose it. maybe i should add that i call this reCompute proc that base the above lines each time i need to re-compute the content of the Items array.  even after adding retain it losing the values Grrr..

Comment: I could not understand why the explicit `retain` did not work. However, if ARC is not an option, using the NS containers is more preferable over C style arrays in ObjC development, which retain their objects automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more careful about the life time of the `NSString` objects.  The `[NSString stringWithBlah]` methods return `autorelease`d instances (so the pointer will be dandling - I'm surprised you aren't getting crashes).

You need to use `[[NSString alloc] initWithBlah]` instead and `release` the instances in `dealloc` (or wherever).

Comment: isn't [code] NSString *jj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10]; for example already have alloc built in?

Comment: @StkStocki No, it's a *convenience constructor* that returns an `autorelease`d object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean (the last line)

```
Items[42] = [@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: j ];
```

instead of:

```
Items[42] = [@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: var1 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this?

```
      Items[42] = [@" Per each " stringByAppendingString: j ];
```

Comment: i did, that's what i meant. I fixed it above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare bare variables in a header file. You will get unexpected results.

In .h:

```
extern double var1;
extern NSString *Items[90];
```

In .m:

```
double var1;
NSString *Items[90];
```